# Pausing execution externally in .net

Tags: c#, .net

I have two processes running on separate machines and I need to synchronize their operation.
Is there a good way to pause code execution externally on demand. (basically like a pause button that one can press and pause the other)?

Comment: In short: no. Processes can be suspended on the OS level, but this is unsafe in that proper operation of the process when it's unsuspended can't be guaranteed that way (it may start hitting timeouts on operations started before the suspend, for example). If you need something like this, you'll have to make them communicate explicitly through whatever IPC mechanism you like (like gRPC over TCP/IP) and put a "stop now and wait" message in the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

You may use a message queue like rabbitmq. Both process can listen same channel and may pause if appropriate message is received.

Comment: Or the other way round: Both process messages that they ping-pong each other. So, what I mean is: they wouldn't _pause_ on message, but _execute_ on message. Which is the more natural way of doing things, if you ask me.

Comment: Makes sense. This can be more easy to manage.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a File for each process. If the file contains "PAUSE", for example, the process could check on that and pauses. Clearly you have to implement that behaviour.

Comment: As somebody that had to work with that kind of text-file based communication: Naaah.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a WebAPI controller to your apps and add as many externally addressable commands as you require. I do this with aspnetcore style or OWIN self-hosted apps, because you can basically easily configure a web server with most of the starter templates, so it's quite easy.

For synchronisation though, I'd consider having the two tasks communicate directly with one-another instead of having and external user start/pause them both.